# Create variable names dynamically based on column headings

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dynamic-variables

Suppose a google sheet column name, PERSON_ID, retrieved by code.

How can I dynamically create a variable with this name? I'm envisioning something like this:

```
var columnName='PERSON_ID';

var [columnName]=''
```

Hopefully, the idea is clear.

Comment: You can create a lot of properties with an object

Comment: Thanks. Not sure where to take that, Cooper. How would I go about taking a value (in this case, PERSON_ID) and dynamically use it, in code, to create a var called PERSON_ID?

Comment: I don't understand precisely what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I begin without a variable and want to dynamically create one with a name found in a column. In this example, I have a column heading called PERSON_ID. What I want to do is retrieve that heading (which is simple) and then use the retrieved name to create a variable with that name. So, I'd be looking for a var called PERSON_ID once the code runs.

Comment: in short, you can't, there is no way you can dynamically name a variable with random string. To accomplish a similar result, we create an Object and set Object keys with dynamical names and the paired value as the value of that so call "dynamical variable".

Comment: I think I get the idea, but I've never used or set properties of an object. Do you have an example that's similar to this case?

Comment: Just checked it out. So far as I can tell, can easily assign var values within the object var, but not the names of the vars themselves.

Comment: Answer is below. Thank you. Other (but different) solutions appear in the search list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to accomplish what I believe you are trying to do:

```js
const variables = {}; // create an empty object and name it "variables".
const ranStr_1 = "ABC";
const ranStr_2 = "XYZ";

// set the string "ABC" and "XYZ" stored in variable 'ranSTR_1' and 'ranSTR_2' as keys inside the Object 'variables', with paired values "value 1" and "value 2".
variables[ranStr_1] = "value 1"; 
variables[ranStr_2] = "value 2";

console.log(variables.ABC) // should shows "value 1" in console.
console.log(variables["ABC"]) // should shows "value 1" in console.
console.log(variables.XYZ) // should shows "value 2" in console.
console.log(variables["XYZ"]) // should shows "value 2" in console.

// you can also do something like this:

const varNames = ["name_1","name_2","name_3","name_4"];

for (const [i,key] of varNames.entries()) {
  variables[key] = i
}

// shows all stored key: value pairs in console:
console.log(variables)
```